# Use a variable to set alpha opacity in a colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I would like to plot the 2 output variables, say *map1* and *map2*, as a function of 2 input variables, say *x* and *y* using colormaps. So as to do so, I want to represent *map1* using a color scale while *map2* would rely on a transparency scale. Yet, the alpha option cannot take an np.array as an argument and the following code is doomed to failure.

```
fig=plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(21,12), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
ax1=plt.subplot(211)
im = ax1.pcolor(map1, cmap='Spectral_r', alpha=map2)
fig.colorbar(im)
```

Would anybody see a way to do this? I don't want to use another overlapped color scale and really want *map2* to be represented with a transparency function so as the visibility of a background grid for instance would tell the reader the amplitude of *map2*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do this with `pcolormesh`, and set the `alpha` for the faces of the `QuadMesh` afterwards. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

# The data array
m1 = np.random.rand(5,5)
# The alpha array. Normalize your map2 to the range 0,1
m2 = np.linspace(0,1,25).reshape(5,5) 

p = ax.pcolormesh(m1)
plt.savefig('myfig.png') # or fig.canvas.draw()

for i,j in zip(p.get_facecolors(),m2.flatten()):
    i[3] = j # Set the alpha value of the RGBA tuple using m2

plt.savefig('myfig.png')
```

Note: you seem to have to save the figure (or `plt.show()` or `fig.canvas.draw()`) after the pcolormesh command, to generate the `p.get_facecolors` array; that's why I save the figure twice. There is probably a more elegant solution to that, but I can't think of it off the top of my head. Here's the output; notice the `alpha` increase from the bottom left towards the top right:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for! It enables me to focus the attention of the reader where things are actually happening while still representing a second variable with a colormap.