# pyplot pcolormesh set_facecolor not updating the plot in jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to update the color of the faces of a pcolormesh using `set_facecolor`. The purpose of this operation is to "bleach" (emulate transparency by whitening the facecolor) some regions of the plot -- see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52100747/changing-facecolor-alpha-value-gives-unwanted-edges-matplotlib-pcolormesh). Although I am pretty sure I have been getting this to work in the past, for some reason it does not work anymore in a jupyter lab or jupyter notebook environment (not tested in a script yet). Unexpectedly, calling `fig.canvas.draw()` seems to restore the initial face colors. Here is a minimal example reproducing the error:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

## Generate data and show initial plot
xx = np.linspace(-1, 1, 5)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(xx, xx)
data = np.exp( -(xx**2+yy**2) )

### Generate plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
hpc = ax.pcolormesh(data)
plt.colorbar(hpc)
ax.set_aspect(1)

fig.canvas.draw()  # this is required to generate the facecolor array
colors = hpc.get_facecolors() # for checking: this contains the RGBA array
newc = np.ones((colors.shape[0], 3))/2. # uniform grey
hpc.set_facecolor(newc) # this should update the facecolor of the plot

newc = hpc.get_facecolors() # indeed, the facecolor seems to have been updated
fig.canvas.draw() # re-generating the plot
### On my machine: the plot is unchanged and the new facecolors are back to the initial values
print(newc[0,:], hpc.get_facecolors()[0,:])
```

Configuration:

- backend: `%matplotlib inline` or `%matplotlib widget` both produce the error
- python 3.9.13 (macOS Big Sur) or python 3.8.11 (Linux on a cluster -- maybe Fedora)
- matplotlib 3.5.1 or 3.5.2 (resp), jupyterlab 3.4.4 or 3.4.0 (resp.)

Does anyone have an idea of what is going on? Am I doing something wrong? Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a "trick" based on [this matplotlib issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/15397) (that I am sure was not necessary with a previous configuration): inserting `hpc.set_array(None)` before calling `set_facecolor` enables achieving the desired result.